# Flutter home page refreshing even after navigated to new page

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I'm using mobx state management and I'm experiencing some strange things in my Flutter App

I've 2 screens in my app, homescreen and a second page

I'm calling my second screen from my home screen like below,

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const DayBookScreen(),
              settings: RouteSettings(arguments: somedata)))
      .then((onGoBack));
```

below is my second screen constructor

```
    class DayBookScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DayBookScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DayBookScreenState createState() => _DayBookScreenState();
}

class _DayBookScreenState extends State<DayBookScreen> {
  TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
}
```

when I change anything on my second screen, the home screen is refreshing and it's calling all the api's.

below is my flutter doctor -v

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 2.0.4 at C:\flutter
• Framework revision b1395592de (8 months ago), 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
• Engine revision 2dce47073a
• Dart version 2.12.2
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Mobx but it's reactive programming and what you are experiencing is just a normal behaviour of state updating.

First of all, when you push a new screen the previous one it's not removed from the stack unless you replace your current home with the second screen with no option to go back. I guess it's not what you need.
So just imagine that the second page is over the homepage. The home is still there alive and refreshing when you change something with Mobx.

If you don't want to call all APIs again, you should put them in a method like "initState" or something similar in your mobx configuration.
Usually, initState is a method called once when the widget is created for the first time.

Comment: good information

Comment: is there any way to call new page without stacking?